# One many query where many has one record

Tags: mysql, one-to-many, relation

I have user table which has many properties. User table having one to many relation. I try to select users which have just one property in properties table

```
select *, count(p.account_id) as c
form accounts as a
left join properties as p on a.account_id = p.account_id
group by p.account_id
having c = 1
```

but this is not seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *, count(*) as num from 
accounts as a INNER JOIN properties as p 
ON a.account_id = p.account_id 
group by p.account_id 
having num=1
```

Comment: I accepted but my issue seems to be related when I make a where on p.table, for example year(p.from) =  2017

Answer (score 1):

You can also make it as a second request:

```
select * 
from (
    SELECT *, p.account_id , count(*) as num 
    from accounts as a 
    INNER JOIN properties as p ON a.account_id = p.account_id 
    group by p.account_id 
) query
where query.num = 1
```

Comment: thanks for feedback this produce for me duplicate account_id

Comment: actually you give a good idea with this to fix my problem. Thanks

Comment: Then i'm glad it has helped. You found out the solution ?